# Isolated Azure Function keep showing old function name

Tags: azure, azure-functions, .net-7.0, azure-functions-isolated

Firstly I created a sample isolated azure function on .net 7 like this

```
> [Function("Function1111")] public HttpResponseData
> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")]
> HttpRequestData req)
> {
>             //_logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
> 
>             var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
>             response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
> 
>             response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
> 
>             return response;
> }
```

After running few rounds to change code, rebuild and re-test, then i renamed the function name to the right name, but when running debug locally, the old name's always displayed.

I after that deleted the whole output bin/obj folder to rebuild, from that on, it always says that No function founds, but my function with new name is there.

Do you have any solution to fix this please ?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you still facing the same issue? Have you redeployed the Azure Function App after making changes ?

Comment: i've resolved it, that issue i got is when trying to move from fuction v3 to v4 and run manually. In short way, you need to remove all the caches of nuget folder which is related to WebJobs and Workers, then build and run again